# What is relative order and what does stable_partition do?

Tags: c++, stl

So I got this code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool isEven(int x) {
    return x % 2 == 0;
}

int main() {

    std::vector<int> vec = {1,7,3,10,9,6};
    std::stable_partition(vec.begin(), vec.end(), isEven);
}
```

Now I didn't understand what was the concrete difference between `stable_partition` and `partition`.

So I looked in my book and it said that:

> stable_partition maintains the relative order of elements in each partition

But I don't understand, **what** is the *relative order* of the elements?

Does it mean that the elements that don't match the partition predicate stay in the same order? if yes, how can they be changed in `std::partition`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the example given, it's not too exciting.  But let's say it was being sorted by the first value of a pair:  `{{1,"one"}, {2,"two"}, {1,"i"}, {2,"ij"}, {1,"uno"}, {2,"dos"}}` ... now maintaining the relative order might be very important, even at the cost of a little performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *relative order* of the elements is simply the order that the elements *within* a particular partition have with respect to each other.

For example, after `partition`ing

```
{1,7,3,10,9,6}
```

we get:

```
   {6,10}  {1,3,7,9}   // one of the possible results
// ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^      elements within partition can be in any order
```

so the relative order is *not* guaranteed to be maintained. Note that 6 comes before 10, whereas it came after 10 before the partitioning.

On the other hand, if you do a `stable_partition`ing, you get:

```
{10,6} {1,7,3,9}   // only possible result
```

and the relative order within each partition is guaranteed to be maintained.

Comment: What are the differences in their complexities?

Answer (score 2):

The relative order means that in respect to the original order, the new partitioned set will maintain that ordering.  In your example that means

```
{1,7,3,10,9,6}
```

become

```
{10,6,1,7,3,9}
```

Since the order of the even and odds does not change, just where in the set they are